# Uncaught SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified

Tags: chromecast, web-audio-api

The following line produced the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified` on the Chromecast device:

```
var audioBuffer = myAudioContext.createBuffer(1, 500 , 8000);
```

I have not tried on other browser.  Any suggestions?

Edit, upon further testing:

Firefox and Chrome Desktop versions have no error.
Safari desktop version does have the same error as the Chromecast device.

Is there another way to do this:  playing raw pcm audio data on the Chromecast device?

Comment: Does this work on the Chrome desktop browser?

Comment: Have you tried using createBufferSource()